# How to verify if a date is valid AND if it is not after the current date in JAVA

Tags: java, date, validation

I have two Strings representing two different dates:

1. The first date is in this form "yyyy-MM"
2. The second one is in this form "yyyy-MM-dddd"

First of all, I'd like to validate if the two dates are valid.
I found how to do it with the string in this form "yyyy-MM-dddd"

```java
public static void isValidDay(String dateToVerify){
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    try {
        sdf.setLenient(false);
        sdf.parse(dateAVerifier);
        LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(dateToVerify);
        LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
        if (date.isAfter(today)) {
            System.out.println("Date in the future");
        }
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        System.out.println("Invalid Date");
    }
}
```

But when I use the same method just changing the SimpleDateFormat, it doesn't work anymore.

```java
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM");
```

How can I verify if "yyyy-MM" format date is valid ?

Then I have to verify if the year and the month for both dates are the same.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: It's a pure date, so you should use the [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html) class. It's the only class that works on dates without time, so there shouldn't be any confusion about that. It even parses that particular date format natively.

Comment: `yyyy-MM` doesn't have a day-of-month. Which day-of-month (e.g. first day-of-month or last day-of-month) do you want to consider for a string in the format, `yyyy-MM` -OR- do you want `yyyy-MM` to be classified as an invalid string?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this.

- use a [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) to parse the date.
- then use [LocalDate.now()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html#now()) to get current date and compare the two.
- if the format is shorter than 10 characters then I presume it is  year/month format compare it as a `YearMonth` date from the first day of the month.
- I modified your method to return a boolean.

```
String today = LocalDate.now()
        .format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd"));

String[] testDates = { "2021-03-31", "2020-11",
        "2022-12", "1996-10-23" };
        
for (String date : testDates) {
    System.out.printf("Today is %s : %-10s is in the %s%n",
            today, date, (isValidDay(date) ? "future" : "past"));
}
```

Today it prints

```
Today is 2021-01-31 : 2021-03-31 is in the future
Today is 2021-01-31 : 2020-11    is in the past
Today is 2021-01-31 : 2022-12    is in the future
Today is 2021-01-31 : 1996-10-23 is in the past
```

The method - returns true or false depending on the outcome.

```
final static DateTimeFormatter dtfymd = 
            DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
final static DateTimeFormatter dtfym = 
            DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM");

public static boolean isValidDay(String dateToVerify) {
    LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
    LocalDate date = null;
    if (dateToVerify.length() < 10) {
        date = YearMonth.parse(dateToVerify, dtfym).atDay(1);
        today = YearMonth.from(today).atDay(1);
    } else {
        date = LocalDate.parse(dateToVerify, dtfymd);
    }
    try {
        return date.isAfter(today);
    } catch (DateTimeParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}
```

When you compare dates and times it is important you take into account the `locale` of each `date/time` object.

Note: I am using `DateTimeFormatter` to fully comply with your specified format requirement.   `LocalDate.parse()` uses `uuuu` for the year which would allow negative years where as `yyyy` does not.

Comment: It’s basically the recommended way (+1). Since as Andreas said, `LocalDate.parse(date)` parses the string, we don’t need the formatter in this case.

Comment: I modified my answer to reflect your new requirements.  Note that you specified `dddd` in your question and `dd` in your example.  I presumed the first was a mistake since it does not make sense.